# Disable future date in Kendo UI Calendar Widget

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

How is it possible to disable (basically i mean just greying out) future dates in Kendo UI Calendar widget? I have only tried to hide future dates but it does not seem to look good and I have tried various way to grey it out but not finding the proper method? Any ideas will be really appreciated.

Comment: [Tried this?](http://dojo.telerik.com/UKUPo) They are not greyed out because the widget simply doesn't renders disabled days.

Comment: Yeap. However I do not want to hide future dates but only grey them out, meaning they cannot be selected by the dates is still displayed. Any idea how that is done? @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: I suspected. but the days are not rendered, check it out by yourself: inspect the blank area which the future days suposed to be displayed, you'll see that there is only `&nbsp; ` chars and not the days. It's a shame but its a widget limitation. If the days were hidden with css, the theme could handle it.

Comment: Well, that actually makes sense now. I have been trying for a day now just to grey it out but it doesn't. Maybe only css is the only way to work around it, Appreciate it @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: I just tried using [disableDates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/calendar#configuration-disableDates) using a function to disable future dates. But however, when I select a date from the previous month, the disabled dates are once again active. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Maybe you're doing the wrong verification. It should return `true` to disable and not the otherwise. Check [this out](http://dojo.telerik.com/IkOHu). Indeed it works.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Brillaint! This works!

Comment: Want an answer of that ?

Comment: Sure @DontVoteMeDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`disableDates`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/calendar#configuration-disableDates) options(that you have find out by yourself) function expects to be told whenever it should display the day. So you have to return true if it is a valid date, e.g.:

```
disableDates: function (date) {
    return (date && date.getTime() > (new Date()).getTime());
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IkOHu)